# - (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender model used generically

Tags: iphone

So I was curious about something and not sure if there is a "standard" or "good" coding practice for something.  If you have a home page for example with 3 buttons (like the facebook iphone app dashboard), that go to various parts of the app by pushing a view controller, then on one button, I would have the IBAction tied to it as:

```
- (IBAction)showSummary:(id)sender {
    SummaryViewController *detailViewController = [[[SummaryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SummaryViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    detailViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    detailViewController.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];   
}
```

So my first question is, let's say on the first time I launch the app, I want to show this page first.  So in viewDidLoad, could I just call this method

```
[self showSummary:nil];
```

Or is it better to just have the same code in my viewDidLoad.

The second question regarding this is refactoring.  If all 3 of my buttons do the same thing in creating a viewController and pushing it onto the stack, the only difference being which viewController to initializer

e.g.

```
SummaryViewController *detailViewController = [[[SummaryViewController alloc]
```

Should I refactor these methods?  If so, what would be a good way to do it?  Thanks!

Comment: This is, technically, two questions in one.  Someone may answer both but I recommend editing your post and splitting this across two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than answer question 1 and 2 separately, I'll just suggest a couple modifications to your code design that will actually answer both questions.

Absolutely don't repeat the code in viewDidLoad.  While this is a simple example, copy/pasting code is never a good idea, one good reason to not do this, is that when you discover a bug in the chunk of code, you will have to apply that change everywhere you copy/pasted it.  Chances are, you'll either be annoyed doing this, or you'll forget one place and leave a lurking bug.   The easiest way to accomplish not copy/pasting your code is to simply  call `[self showSummary:nil];`  I would suggest an even cleaner approach though, as it doesn't make sense to use the "sender" parameter from the context of viewDidLoad.

Here's what I'll propose (this assumes you have your three buttons already setup as button1, button2, and button3.  Replace those variables with your own):

```
- (IBAction)showSummary:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *detailViewController = nil;
    if (sender == self.button1) {
        detailViewController = [[[SummaryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SummaryViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else if (sender == self.button2) {
        detailViewController = [[[SummaryViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"SummaryViewController2" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else if (sender == self.button3) {
        detailViewController = [[[SummaryViewController3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"SummaryViewController3" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }

    //You can accomplish these two lines in the nib file.  Do it there unless there's a reason to change these separately per controller, it simplifies the code
    //detailViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    //detailViewController.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];   
}
```

Then from viewDidLoad, call the method specifying the button for which you want to simulate an action.

```
- (viewDidLoad) {
    [self showSummary:self.button1];
}
```

Now some would argue that's a little unreadable, because as a 3rd party person looking at your code, I'm wondering why you are passing the button to that method.  Instead, you could consider refactoring showSummary to an additional method that separate the logic of translating an action (either a button, or some other flag) and actually doing the action (pushing the navigation controller).

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Don't repeat the code just use `[self showSummary:nil];`

Question 2:  Do repeat the code. They are different objects with different tasks so keep them separate.